# Prism: Nested Regions

Tags: prism, mef

I googled a lot but i didn't find an exact answer.
I'm using Prism-Mef, i have RegionB which is nested inside RegionA
 When i declare:

```
IRegion regionB= regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.RegionB];
```

i got the exception:

```
The region manager does not contain the RegionB region.
```

- 1-How i can access RegionB to Add view to it, knowing that i will use
  it as a scoped region.
- 2-If i have a third level of nesting: for example RegionC which is
  nested inside RegionB, how can use RegionC to add a View

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you created a scoped RegionManager - you need to use the scoped region manager of the view that contains the inner region.

```
var scopedRegionManager = RegionManager.GetRegionManager(view);
var regionB = scopedRegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.RegionB];
```